# How do I align this icon while having the input take 100% width?

Tags: html, css

I have the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stpra123/7cap7o7s/2/

The first input has the icond correctly aligned but when I try to make the input tag take up 100% of it's width I can't seem to figure out how to get the icon to align correctly. Any suggestions? I am using the cascade css framework and fontawesome.

```
<div class="site-body">
    <div class="site-center">
        <div class="cell">
            <form>
                <input id="first" value="I am correct!" />
                <i class="fa fa-calendar first"></i>
            </form>
            <form>
                <input id="second" value="I am a bit messed up!" />
                <i class="fa fa-calendar second"></i>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

form {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#first {
    width: 90%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.first {
    position: relative;
    left: -30px;
}
#second {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.second {
    position: relative;
    left: -30px;
}
```

EDIT: I need the input to take up 100% of the width because I have content below it that also takes up 100% of the width and if I set the input to 90% then it looks funny compared to the content below it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would wrap the input tag in a 'div' tag:

**HTML**

```
<div class="inputCont">
     <input id="second" value="I am a bit messed up!" />
     <i class="fa fa-calendar second"></i>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.inputCont {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.second {
    position: absolute;
    right: 4px;
    top: 8px;
}
```

[Here's an updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremyhawes/7cap7o7s/3/)